# Using add/remove when searching multiple indices with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) on searching multiple indices states:

> Most APIs that refer to an index parameter support execution across multiple indices, using simple test1,test2,test3 notation (or _all for all indices). It also support wildcards, for example: test* or *test or te*t or *test*, and the ability to "add" (+) and "remove" (-), for example: +test*,-test3.

If I understand this correctly, "-" in front of an index means that this particular index will be excluded. However, I'm not sure I understand the "+". Can it be interpreted as "must be included"? What would be the difference between `+test*,-test3` and `test*,-test3`?

Comment: I don't see any description for "-" or "+". In the documentation it just says you can use "*" character to match anything. I use "-" as part of my index name even.

Comment: my guess is that it means "add if not exists" . Its based on simple test that i did, `POST /idx1/search` and `POST /idx1,idx1/search` do not re-use the query cache while `POST /idx1,%2Bidx1/search` re-uses the query cache. But this is certainly not a definitive answer.